# Identifying requests made by Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a web application that has some pretty intuitive URLs, so people have written some Chrome extensions that use these URLs to make requests to our servers. Unfortunately, these extensions case problems for us, hammering our servers, issuing malformed requests, etc, so we are trying to figure out how to block them, or at least make it difficult to craft requests to our servers to dissuade these extensions from being used (we provide an API they should use instead).

We've tried adding some custom headers to requests and junk-json-preamble to responses, but the extension authors have updated their code to match.

I'm not familiar with chrome extensions, so what sort of access to the host page do they have? Can they call JavaScript functions on the host page? Is there a special header the browser includes to distinguish between host-page requests and extension requests? Can the host page inspect the list of extensions and deny certain ones?

Some options we've considered are:

1. Rate-limiting QPS by user, but the problem is not all queries are equal, and extensions typically kick off several expensive queries that look like user entered queries.
2. Restricting the amount of server time a user can use, but the problem is that users might hit this limit by just navigating around or running expensive queries several times.
3. Adding static custom headers/response text, but they've updated their code to mimic our code.
4. Figuring out some sort of token (probably cryptographic in some way) we include in our requests that the extension can't easily guess. We minify/obfuscate our JS, so are ok with embedding it in the JS source code (since the variable name it would have would be hard to guess).

I realize this may not be a 100% solvable problem, but we hope to either give us an upper hand in combatting it, or make it sufficiently hard to scrape our UI that fewer people do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, guess nobody knows. In the end we just sent a custom header and starting tracking who wasn't sending it.